# how can I load a component from a jsp into another jsp?

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

I was told I could load a single component from a jsp file through his id, I'm using this:

```
            <sj:div id="div1" class="text"
                href="%{urlObtenerCaracteristicasTipoProyecto}"
                indicator="indicator1"
                reloadTopics="reloadCaracteristicasTipoProyecto"
                deferredLoading="true" formIds="frmProyectoGubernamental">
            </sj:div>
```

but that piece of code retrieves the whole jsp file, decorators included, I'm only interested in retrieving just one component from one jsp file to insert into the div1 owner's jsp file.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want specific HTML returned, you need to return only that HTML. The easiest way to do that is to have an action that renders just the portion of JSP in question, like the contents of a specific `<div>`, etc. The other option is to return JSON and render HTML via JavaScript using that JSON.

You can't retrieve just a portion of HTML by putting anything on the URL--try it from the address bar, at best you'll scroll to that location.

(Unless the system uses the URL to determine what's sent back, obviously.)